# how to apply the module pattern in a node.js console application?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to apply the module-augmentation JavaScript pattern explained [here](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth.html) to a console node.js application.

First I have the file `get-set.js` which implements a simple module with only `get` and `set` methods:

```
var module = (function() {
    var x = 0;
    function get() {return x;}
    function set(_x) {x = _x;}
    return {
        get: get,
        set: set};
})();

module.set(10);
console.log(module.get());
```

The above code works.
Now, I am trying to follow the next step in the pattern and located some additional functionality (say a method to increment the counter) in a separate file `get-set-inc.js`:

```
require('./get-set.js');

var module = (function(m) {
    function inc() {m.set(m.get()+1);}
    m.inc = inc;
    return m;
})(module);

module.inc();
console.log(module.get());
```

Unfortunately when I run the latter file under node.js I don't succeed to augment the module. In fact I get:

```
$ ls
get-set-inc.js  get-set.js
$
$ node get-set-inc.js 
10

[...]/get-set-inc.js:4
        function inc() {m.set(m.get()+1);}
                                ^
TypeError: Object #<Module> has no method 'get'
    at Module.inc ([...]/get-set-inc.js:4:33)
    at Object.<anonymous> ([...]/get-set-inc.js:9:12)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:929:3
```

Upon further inspection I've come to realize that the problem lies in the use of `require`. How then should I load the external JavaScript file in a `node` application so that I can follow the various Augmentation patterns discussed in the link above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First the code then some notes below.

### **get-set.js**

```
module.exports = function gsFactory() {
  var x = 0;

  function get() {
    return x;
  }

  function set(_x) {
    x = _x;
  }
  return {
    get: get,
    set: set
  };
}

//prints 0
console.log(module.exports().get());
```

### **get-set-inc.js**

```
var gs = require('./get-set');

module.exports = function gsiFactory() {
  var instance = gs();
  function inc() {
    instance.set(instance.get()+1);
  }
  instance.inc = inc;
  return instance;
};

// demo
var gsi = module.exports();
gsi.inc();
// this prints 1
console.log(gsi.get());
gsi.inc();
// this prints 2
console.log(gsi.get());
```

---

```
node get-set-inc.js
0
1
2
```

That's what I gather you intend to build. One issue is `module` is predefine in node.js by the wrapper function so don't use "module" as a variable name because you'll clobber the CommonJS "module" name meaning you won't be able to properly export your API.

In general in node, all CommonJS modules are automatically wrapped in a function, so there's no need to include IIFE wrapper code. The [wrapper code](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/d8baf8a2a4481940bfed0196308ae6189ca18eee/src/node.js#L795) looks like this:

```
NativeModule.wrapper = [
  '(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { ',
  '\n});'
];
```

To export a factory function (which is how I think about this pattern), just assign `module.exports` to be that function. This is quite common in node (express does this, many connect middleware modules, etc).

The way above doesn't use constructor functions or prototypes. It's perhaps simpler to understand but it has the disadvantage of defining new and distinct `get`, `set`, and `inc` methods each time. If you exported a constructor function that accessed methods defined just once on the prototype, all instances could share those methods. A bit of a micro-optimization but it's good to understand how to code it both ways.